# Service worker and custom push notifications

Tags: javascript, websocket, notifications, service-worker

My application uses websocket to deal with push notifications when the user has the app open in his browser ( active tab or not ).

My backend is responsible for emitting events via websocket that I catch on frontend thanks to socket.io, and then display it with browser native Notification system.

What I want to achieve here is having a service worker to display those notifications even when the user isn't on my app webpage or has its browser closed ( Like Facebook, YouTube, Asana or Slack does ), but after a while searching for resources to do so, I can't tell if it's even possible to do it without using third-part services like Google GCM.

Is it possible to catch events from my websocket backend inside a service worker to show notifications ? And if so, how may I proceed ?

Comment: you won't be able to trigger service worker without using gcm.
you could use a third party application like https://pushcrew.com/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI44Ls6Iy51QIVUAYqCh1mQwlgEAAYASAAEgJVWPD_BwE
who will be able to handle those things for you

Comment: Are Facebook, Slack etc... using those too ? I thought that those kind of services where useful when you wanted to send "global" notifications like "Hey we've have this new feature .. !" to all your users. But when it comes to specific notifications like "You have a new comment", is it still usable ?

Comment: yes you can target the user based on the info u store along with it. when u get a subscription id u can save email-Id or userId along with the subscription id thereby allowing u to target a specific user for comment and stuffs

Comment: Found this google codelab : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/ ,what do you think ?

Comment: It is the same what i was talking about they are also using gcm only to send the mess in backend

Comment: It's complicated, some people say it's possible, others say no. See [this for more info](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/947)

Comment: I have same question. If service worker can keep websocket up and running - can't messages received by websocket client invoke Notification api? It seems to work. Though I am not sure if this is the right way to do device notifications. Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks, Sandeep